# Canon 550d viewfinder exposure information issue after firmware update

Tags: canon, canon-550d, live-view, firmware

I recently updated the firmware on my T2i and when I am metering a room either through the viewfinder or my LCD screen the ISO and exposure information will only stay onscreen for 2 seconds.  If I'm trying to dial in exposure or aperture information, I have to keep pressing my shutter halfway to get the information back up.  Is there a setting I am overlooking to keep this information displayed or has anyone noticed this as an issue after firmware upgrading to 1.0.9?

**UPDATE  After looking closely at my camera, my issue seems to be that when I have live view on and am looking at the lcd, if I meter, as soon as i release the shutter the iso/exposure information goes away.  If I press the A+/- button to the right, I get my ISO/exposure information for two seconds.  Not useful when I'm trying to meter all around a room with live view.  I keep having to press the shutter button down halfway.  Searching through my menus, I cannot seem to find any function that controls this.

**UPDATE Thank you to the posters leaving comments, however I'd like to reiterate that this is a 550d (T2i), not a 50D.

Comment: Most likely your firmware reset your Setup and you have to change the Meter Operating Time back to something longer, say 30 seconds. I'm just guessing though :)

Comment: I'd like to find out what it's called on this camera and where it's located in my system menu.

Comment: On Canon, the *Setup* menu is distinguished by a wrench icon. The list is linear below that and if you do not find *Meter Operating Time* at the top-level, try under *Live View Settings*.

Comment: @Itai's right: on the 50D it is be under *Live view function settings*, *Metering Timer*.

Comment: Please see my comment below.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from the [manual](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/9/0300004289/02/eosrt2i-eos550d-im3-c-en.pdf) at page 112 under the *Live view function settings* tab of the menu you can find the *Metering timer* option which does the following:

> You can change how long the exposure setting is displayed (AE lock time).

Comment: I tried this setting, tried all the way up to 30 minutes.  I am having the same problem no matter if I set it to 1 second or 30 minutes.

Comment: Have you tried the good old time tested method to remove the battery and leave the camera alone for some minute?

Comment: Well, I had the battery out for several days...so, this was not a fix.  Not sure what I should do.